# In ModelBuilder use Parse Path (path and name) to get output FC name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-path, address-parsing

I built a model (in ArcGIS 10.6) and the Parse Path tool is working well if I using the Name type.

But I need to use the input .gdb name also into the output feature class name. e.g.

Inputs:

```
C:\clip\seeq.gdb\v1; C:\clip\lake.gdb\v1; C:\clip\lake.gdb\v2; C:\clip\lake.gdb\v3; C:\clip4q\hill.gdb\v1...
```

and I like to get these output FC names:

```
seeq_v1; lake_v1; lake_v2; lake_v3; hill_v1...
```

How could I use path? Or could you know something helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can already get the name of the FC. To get the name of the gdb, do Parse Path w/ "PATH" as parse type, and then use the results as the input to another Parse Path, this time w/ "NAME" as parse type.

Might look something like this:

[image]

[image]